# Fix function not working in R

Tags: r

I am having some difficulty using the fix function in R. I loaded a data set using the following code before applying fix

```
college = read.csv("College.csv")
fix("College.csv")
```

However, instead of a window popping up with the dataframe to view, I get this instead: 
[image]

Please does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to run:

```
fix(college)
```

and not with a string.

**Help:**

> Usage
>
> ```
> fix(x, ...) Arguments
> x  the name of an R object, as a name or a character string.
> ...    arguments to pass to editor: see edit.
> ```

So, you can also use `fix("college")`.

Comment: And what version of R you are using? In R 3.1.0 it works, I checked on custom csv.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally got it to work. I simply clicked on the view option located in the Data section of the Global Environment screen. I was under the impression that the data window would automatically pop up once "fix" is run, however this is not the case for me.